# What do red threads mean in Eclipse Debug View?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

During debugging my Java Application in Eclipse, the Debug View shows some threads in red text color and with a lock symbol:

[image: some threads are shown in red, in Eclipse debug view]

Can anyone explain what this means?

I'm currently looking for (potential) deadlocks in my code. That's why the red threads bother me. But those threads are obviously not involved in a deadlock situation, when I suspend the VM:

[image]

I studied the [Eclipse help pages for Debug View](https://help.eclipse.org/2021-03/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/debug/ref-debug_view.htm), but found no explanation there.

**EDIT:** as @howlger correctly points out, there is a note on the [Eclipse Tips and Tricks (JDT)](https://help.eclipse.org/2021-03/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tips/jdt_tips.html?cp=1_5_6#debugging_section) page, stating "... Threads involved in a deadlock are rendered in red. ...". But does that also mean deadlock detection is the **only** reason for rendering the threads in red? If so, my case might just be a false positive guess by the eclipse internal heuristics. As soon as I suspend my VM, eclipse investigates monitor ownership in full detail and finds that there is no actual deadlock situation. This also aligns with the suspended thread appearance (my second screenshot, above): the threads are suddenly not red anymore, when suspended.

Comment: Deadlock detection is a capability of the Java VM, not an Eclipse internal heuristic. The documentation is very clear about what red means here (see my answer). And of course it is the **only** reason (otherwise it would be a bug of a violation of the UI guidelines). If you want to know what's going on with your code, ask that as a separate question by showing your code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (and please be more specific, e.g. _deadlock situation_ is not a term used in the UI or documentation, so you need to specify it).

Comment: There is obviously a real chance for occasional inconsistent visualization of thread states in this DebugView. It occurs sometimes in my full blown application. I have tried to reproduce it in a small example with three simple threads. But then the effect didn't show up. I don't think its a bug or anything. I can imagine that Eclipse hasn't all the exact information at hand at all times.

Comment: I took my time to answer your question _"What do red threads mean in Eclipse Debug View?"_ and back it up with a link to the official documentation. I asked you if in your case the threads wait forever, which you didn't answer. You wrote about _"(potential) deadlocks"_ and _"obviously not involved in a deadlock situation"_ showing two cropped screenshots. I'm able to reproduce the screenshot with a deadlock, so saying it's _obviously_ does not make sense with the information provided.

Comment: Please read the [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct#unacceptable-behavior) and consider to delete your _"I get the impression you are neither trying to understand my question nor to be helpful with regard to this effect..."_ comment as it is neither nice nor true nor adds value.

Answer (score 1):

The threads in red are **involved in a deadlock**, but you have to enable ***Show Monitors*** to see also which **tread owns** which object.

See the [Eclipse Tips and Tricks (JDT)](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tips/jdt_tips.html#debugging_section) help page:

> **Threads and monitors**
>
> The Java debugger optionally displays monitor information in the
> **Debug** view. Use the **Show Monitors** action in the Debug view drop down menu to show which threads are holding locks and which are
> waiting to acquire locks. Threads involved in a deadlock are rendered
> in red.
>
> [image: Threads and monitors]

Comment: Thank you, but I always have **Show monitors** enabled. I can usually see actual deadlocks in the same way your screenshot shows.

Comment: You might also enable _Show System Threads_ in case the object being waited for is owned by a system thread.

Comment: OK, I didn't have **Show System Threads** enabled before. Activated it now. Reproduced the situation. Unfortunately it does not change the appearance of the effect.

Comment: What do you mean by _"the appearance of the effect"_? You cannot find the threads that own the locks the three threads shown in your cropped screenshots are waiting for?

Comment: Same appearance. Meaning I could just copy the two images from my original post and post them again here (which I spare us).

Also the threads in red are unlikely to produce deadlocks they are instances of the same, very simple Runnable, just waiting for a notify() or notifyAll(). They own no other locks/objects.

Comment: Red does not necessarily mean _produces deadlock_, only _involved in a deadlock_, e.g. a thread waiting for a lock object that is or was also owned by another thread that is deadlocked with a third thread and the deadlock is "produced" by different lock objects the first thread is waiting for. Without knowing the code and only having the cropped screenshots showing only some threads at a point in time unknown, it's impossible to tell what's going on in your case. In short, the red threads have been recognized as being locked forever (it does not mean they are causing the deadlock).

Comment: Ok, I see: you are quite convinced about the deadlock involvment. But I am not. None of the other threads were highlighted in red. Only these 3. I'll try to reproduce this with a very basic main() method. Maybe I can post the source code, if it works.

Comment: That is not what I said. Eclipse gets via the [Java Debug Wire Protocol (JDWP)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/specs/jdwp/jdwp-spec.html) the information which threads own which locks and on which they are waiting for. With that information Eclipse computes whether there are deadlocks (waiting-for-owns-lock cycles) and then marks all in red owning or waiting for lock objects involved in such a deadlock cycle. I'm able to proof by an example that your assumption that red means causing a deadlook is wrong. I'm pretty sure Eclipse does not randomly color things in red.

Comment: Hmm, yes. Maybe I didn't get you right. That was actually my initial question: what else can cause Eclipse to mark the threads in red and with a lock symbol - given there is no deadlock?
Would be useful to understand.

Comment: The threads have a lock symbol because they are waiting for a lock, or is _"waiting for..."_ displayed in the second screenshot by mistake? What make you say _"there is no deadlock"_? In your case, do the threads wait forever or when exactly and by what exactly are they notified/continued (only in the second case, you can be sure that there is no deadlock)? Are you aware that the deadlock detection is and can be done only on paused threads? The _"obviously not involved in a deadlock"_ above a screenshot showing threads waiting for but not owning is - as already explained - a wrong assumption.

Comment: I really try to follow you. Chances of misinterpretations are increasing. Are you trying to say "there is a deadlock" or "there is no deadlock" or "It depends"?

Comment: According to the documentation, red means Eclipse has detected a deadlock. According to the shown screenshots shown in your question, there can be a deadlock. You asked _"What do red threads mean in Eclipse Debug View?"_ and I answered it by pointing you to the documentation. If and only if a thread that is displayed in red will be continued, report it as bug with an example to reproduce it. Again, I answered the question you asked. I didn't say anything about your code since I don't know it.